# mtaylor MuPAD - Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, mupad

I am trying to run the function `mtaylor` from the MuPAD engine in MatLab, which provides a multivariate Taylor expansion of a function. However, it keeps telling me I am trying to expand around an invalid point. Here is a minimal working example of what I tried:

```
syms x y;
feval(symengine,'mtaylor',exp(x^2 - y), [x, y], 4)

Error message:
 vError using mupadengine/feval (line 157)
 MuPAD error: Error: Invalid expansion point. [mtaylor]
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: I don't understand the difference to `evalin(symengine,'mtaylor(exp(x^2 - y), [x, y], 4)')` which runs without an error.

Comment: @Daniel: see my answer for the subtle reason why.

Comment: JFTR, since at least R2012b, you can simply call `taylor(exp(x^2-1), [x,y], 4)` in MATLAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this works with MuPAD's [`mtaylor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/mtaylor.html)

```
syms x y;
feval(symengine,'mtaylor',exp(x^2 - y), x, 4)  % [x] is fine too
```

and this doesn't

```
syms x y;
feval(symengine,'mtaylor',exp(x^2 - y), [x, y], 4)
```

is that the `[x, y]` argument is seen as a single symbolic vector argument/variable rather than a list of variables for the expansion. Your expression, `exp(x^2 - y)`, is not in terms of vector variables, but simple scalars, `x` and `y`.

The workaround is to pass the list as a string:

```
syms x y;
feval(symengine,'mtaylor',exp(x^2 - y), '[x, y]', 4)
```

or

```
syms x y;
feval(symengine,'mtaylor',exp(x^2 - y), ['[' char(x) ',' char(y) ']'], 4)
```

or use [`evalin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/evalin.html) to write the MuPAD command a single string as suggested by @Daniel in the comments:

```
syms x y;
evalin(symengine,'mtaylor(exp(x^2 - y), [x, y], 4)')
```

**Arrays and Matrices vs. Lists in MuPAD**
For further clarification, arrays of symbolic variables in Matlab correspond to the MuPAD [`array`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/array.html) type, which can be created via `feval(symengine,'array','1..1','1..2','[x,y]')`. More specifically, they are of type [`Dom::Matrix()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/dom-matrix.html), which can be created via `V=feval(symengine,'Dom::Matrix()','[x,y]')` or just `syms x y;` `V=[x,y]`.

The `mtaylor` function requires a list input, which can be created via `L=evalin(symengine,'[x,y]')`. Thus

```
syms x y;
feval(symengine,'mtaylor',exp(x^2 - y), V, 4)
```

will produce the same error as in your question, but

```
syms x y;
feval(symengine,'mtaylor',exp(x^2 - y), L, 4)
```

will work correctly. Unfortunately, `L` and `V` appear identical from within Matlab, but you can use MuPAD's [`domtype`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/domtype.html) function to differentiate them:

```
feval(symengine,'domtype',V)
feval(symengine,'domtype',L)
```

which returns `Dom::Matrix()` and `DOM_LIST`.